# Did Adi Shankara persecute Buddhists in Nagarjunakonda?

Tags: history, adi-shankaracharya, buddhism

Neo-Buddhists often claim that Adi Shankaracharya killed many Buddhists and destroyed many Buddhist shrines in Nargarjunakonda, Andhra Pradesh. They also say there is a local legend which supports this point. How far are these claims true?

Comment: If my assessment is correct @sv. is the correct person for providing an answer to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the baseless accusations that Neo-Buddhists have leveled against Adi Shankaracharya is that he persecuted Buddhists, destroyed Nagarjunakonda and Amaravati etc. Proselytization by force, deception or material benefits was not prevalent in those times - be it Hinduism , Jainism or Buddhism. The practice was that the vanquished in a philosophical debate would embrace the faith of the winner.

When it comes to Nagarjunakonda all the Neo-Buddhist blogs, articles etc have one reference - Albert Longhurst's work [Memoirs of Archaelogical Survey of India No. 54, The Buddhist Antiquites of Nagarjuna Konda (Delhi, 1938, page 6)](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.84003/page/n17).

If one looks at page 6, this is what is written - *Local tradition relates that the great Hindu philosopher and teacher Sankaracharya of medieval times came to Nagarjunakonda with a host of followers and destroyed the Buddhist monuments*

So basically A. Longhurst has provided no reference other than local legends, and the Neo-Buddhists keep citing his work as proof

Comment: Yes, this mention of local legend is exactly what I am looking for. So, bounty goes to you, even though the rest of your answer is based on opinion.

Comment: Also, the Ashokavandana claims that Ashoka persecuted Ajvikas when in fact there are inscriptions that say he patronized them Buddhist sources are biased.